# how to exclude unnecessary URLs in ZAP html report

Tags: security, owasp, zap

We are using python selenium and OWASP ZAP API to scan the sites automatically. Finally we will use the code below to generate html issue report.

```
file1.write(zap.core.htmlreport(apikey=apikey))
```

The only issue is, the report contains the too many unnecessary URLs, such as googleapis, facebook, typekit, etc...

We really want to exclude these URLs, we create a new ZAP context, and try to exclude the URLs as:

```
z.context.exclude_from_context(contextname=cname, regex=regex, apikey=apikey)
```

the regex is regular expression as :

```
^http(s)?:\/\/([a-z0-9\-]+.)+(facebook|google).(com|net)\/?
```

but it doesn't work.... The html still contains the URLs

Anyone could help me ? we want to exclude these URLs or only include the URLs we need in html report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved a similar problem to Python.
I can offer what happened:
"((http[s]?|ftp)://)?([^ -:/][^:/\s]+).\w+((/\w+)*/)([\w-.]+[^ \s:]+)?"

Also, there is a selection with regular expressions from different authors, maybe something will work, but they were not looking very smoothly:
https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

And here I tested, it turned out to be very convenient:
https://regex101.com/